# "Default" button in Lubuntu's notification area

Tags: lubuntu, notification, notification-area

I've just installed Dropbox in Lubuntu and I got the popup notification telling me that I've linked a new computer to my Dropbox account. However, instead of clicking on the "x" in the upper right corner of the notification box, I clicked on the "Default" button, but apparently nothing happened.

What is the purpose of that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default button should clear all notification.

Comment: So the "x" should clear a single notification?

Comment: Yes x is for single notification remove.